# vue 3, cant figure out how to display this data properly

Tags: javascript, axios, vuejs3

im using axios to fetch some json from my django backend, the api call works and i can see the results when i console.log them

for some reason when i load the page i get an error that my data in undefined but i if comment out the code where my data gets displayed in the template it dosnt give me any errors

when i un-comment that code, vite reloads my browser and the data gets diplayed properly until i refresh

**why does this happen and how can i fix this**

heres my code

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from "vue";
import { useProductsStore } from "../stores/products";
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import axios from 'axios'


const store = useProductsStore();

const route = useRoute()

let id = route.params.id
let deets = ref({
  name: "Loading",
  description: "Loading",
  sku: "Loading",
  asin: "Loading"
})
let link = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/" + id

async function getDeets(link) {
  try {
    const data = await axios.get(link)
    deets = data.data;
    console.log(deets)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

onMounted(() => {
  getDeets(link)

})



</script>


<template>
  <div class='deets'>
    <h1>Product Details</h1>
    <hr>
    <h2>Name: {{ deets.name }}</h2>
    <h3>Description: {{ deets.description }}</h3>
    <h2>Sku: {{ deets.sku }}</h2>
    <h3>Asin: {{ deets.asin }}</h3>

    <!-- <h3>{{ deets.price }}</h3> -->

  </div>
</template>  


<style scoped>
.deets {
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
```

i am having a similar problem on a different component and i suspect its because by the time the browser renders the template my api call hasnt run yet so therefore it IS undefined but when vite does a hmr update it works

my other component shows a table of all the products in my db and it works fine unless im navigating back to that page in which case it dosnt display the data until i refresh

Comment: This is happening for 2 reasons. 1) your initial state for deets is undefined which will cause the page to show undefined until the variable changes. 2) You need to ensure you're using reactivity properly to have the data update when it is fetched

Comment: what can i set deets to if i dont have the data yet but i need to declare the variable?

Comment: also what am i doing wrong with the reactivity?

Comment: deets should start as a template object: { name: "Loading", description: "Loading" } etc. You're using the composition API so deets should be a ref.

Comment: thanks for replying but im still a little lost can u explain a little more

Comment: I'm not sure what else to explain. What are you having trouble understanding? Have you read Vue3 docs on reactivity and how Vue works in general?

Comment: i made deets into a template object and a ref and that renders but i dont understand why its not updating once my api call is returned

Comment: how should my code look?

Comment: Can you update your post with your updated code? And it would also be helpful if you can show an example API response for your get request

Comment: at this point when i console.log(deets) i get all the info instead of it being undefined but my template isnt updating to show that info, it just shows "loading"

Comment: Please see my above comment

Comment: heres my api response {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "beans",
    "description": "big ol can o beans",
    "sku": "beansbeansbeans",
    "asin": "bB00nvn",
    "brand": 2,
    "vendors": []
}

Comment: do i need to use a watcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong in 3 places.
Wrong places are marked with //wrong and corrected.

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from "vue";
import { useProductsStore } from "../stores/products";
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import axios from 'axios'


const store = useProductsStore();

const route = useRoute()

let id = route.params.id
const deets = ref({          //wrong
  name: "Loading",
  description: "Loading",
  sku: "Loading",
  asin: "Loading"
})
let link = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/" + id

async function getDeets(link) {
  try {
    const data = await axios.get(link)
    deets.value = data.data;          //wrong
    console.log(deets.value)          //wrong
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

onMounted(() => {
  getDeets(link)

})



</script>


<template>
  <div class='deets'>
    <h1>Product Details</h1>
    <hr>
    <h2>Name: {{ deets.name }}</h2>
    <h3>Description: {{ deets.description }}</h3>
    <h2>Sku: {{ deets.sku }}</h2>
    <h3>Asin: {{ deets.asin }}</h3>

    <!-- <h3>{{ deets.price }}</h3> -->

  </div>
</template>  


<style scoped>
.deets {
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
```

The ref data in the script section needs .value to access.
Also, the ref type must always be const.